# Devise Token Auth - versioned API: uninitialized constant ApplicationController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-api

I am integrating [Devise Token Auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth) into my **versioned** Rails 5 API. Here is the structure:

**Gemfile**:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
...
gem 'omniauth', '~> 1.3'
gem 'devise_token_auth', '~> 0.1.38'
...
```

**routes.rb**:

```
require "api_constraints"

Rails.application.routes.draw do

  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
    scope module: :v1, constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 1, default: true) do
      mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth'
      resources :users
    end
  end
end
```

**application_controller.rb (app/controllers/api/v1/)**:

```
module Api
  module V1
    class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
      include ActionController::Serialization
      include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::SetUserByToken
    end
  end
end
```

When I try to POST:

```
{
    "email": "testuser@domain.com",
    "password": "testuserpassword"
}
```

to `/api/auth/sign_in`, I get the error **`ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant ApplicationController)`**.

It seems that the `devise_controller` doesn't have access to `ApplicationController` when it tries to call its own methods. So I tried setting the base controller:

`mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth', base_controller: 'Api::V1::ApplicationController'`

That also didn't work.

To fix the issue, I could remove the `module` separation in `application_controller.rb` to make it:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
    include ActionController::Serialization
    include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::SetUserByToken
end
```

but that of course causes a different load error (because things are no longer scoped correctly): `LoadError (Unable to autoload constant Api::V1::ApplicationController, expected /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/controllers/api/v1/application_controller.rb to define it)`.

The only thing that actually works is to not have it scoped in a namespace/module at all:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth'

  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
    scope module: :v1,
                  constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 1, default: true) do
      resources :users
    end
  end
end
```

but that defeats the whole purpose of versioning. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have that fancy default scoping happening, but this works for me:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api do
    scope :v1 do
      mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth'
    end
  end
end
```

A big difference is that in addition to my normal scoped-by-version ApplicationController, I have an ApplicationController at `app/controller/application_controller.rb` that reads:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::SetUserByToken
end
```

This may not be ideal, but it works with how DeviseTokenAuth is currently designed.  A proper fix would likely involve a change inside of DeviseTokenAuth itself.

Hopefully this is helpful.  With the above code, I have the following route that works to do what I need it to do:

`api_user_session POST   /api/v1/auth/sign_in(.:format)        devise_token_auth/sessions#create`

. . .  and I don't get the 'different load error' you mentioned when you attempted a similar solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm at work right now so I can't test this, but I will in a couple of hours.

Comment: This did the trick, although I feel like I had already tried that... I guess not! In case that you actually have multiple versions to your API, I needed to make the scope: `scope :v1, as: :v1` in order to not have the error: `Invalid route name, already in use: 'new_api_user_session'`. The versions could also be namespaced instead of scoped, which would solve that issue, but that seems to leave the overall structure less flexible.

Answer (score 1):

Devise tries to make its built-in controllers inherit from your own `ApplicationController`, but in your app that class doesn't exist. Instead you have an `Api::V1::ApplicationController` class.

Fortunately you can configure Devise to inherit from something else. In your `config/initializers/devise.rb`, do this:

```
config.parent_controller = 'Api::V1::ApplicationController'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Paul, but that defeats the purpose of versioning, since only one API version could have the correct parent controller.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone lands here with the same error. The answer from @Ecnalyr helped me a lot but was not enough because sometimes my request would call only `controllers/api/v1/application_controller.rb` and sometimes only `controllers/application_controller.rb` (and for other specific reasons related to my particular needs).

So here is what I did :

```
# controllers/base_controller.rb
class BaseController < ActionController::API
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::SetUserByToken
  include ActionController::Serialization

  before_action :set_global_headers

  private

  def set_global_headers
    response.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
    response.headers["X-Robots-Tag"] = "none"
  end
end
```

So **BaseController** is my crossing controller for global configuration.

```
# controllers/api/v1/application_controller.rb
module Api
  module V1
    class ApplicationController < BaseController
      include Api::V1::ResponseHelper # app/helpers/api/v1/response_helper.rb

      before_action :authenticate_api_v1_user!, except: [:new, :create]
      before_action :set_v1_headers

      private

      def set_v1_headers
        # Custom header specific to v1
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I then added `config.parent_controller = 'BaseController'` to the devise.rb in initializers.

My routes looks like this :

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', as: 'v1', at: 'auth', controllers: {
      token_validations:  'api/v1/users/token_validations',
      registrations:      'api/v1/users/registrations',
      passwords:          'api/v1/users/passwords',
      sessions:           'api/v1/users/sessions'
    }
  end
end
```

I added the Devise user controllers with my controllers just in case I have to edit them.

```
# controllers/api/v1/users/registrations_controller.rb
module Api
  module V1
    module Users
      class RegistrationsController < DeviseTokenAuth::RegistrationsController
        def create
          puts params # For debug
          super
          # Some action after registration
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I think that's all.

Comment: sorry @Stéphane, I need answers to some of this questions.

what is the content of your app/helpers/api/v1/response_helper.rb.?
why are you setting global headers in you base controller?
Also, do you have to create each of the devise controllers (registration/token_validations/password/session) even when you don't need to edit them?

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to remember that my `user[email]` and `user[password]` when testing over Postman had to be updated to the namespaced version e.g. `my_v1_namespace_user[email]` and everything started working again.